# Using HDF5 from C# for realtime data

Tags: c#, hdf5

I am able to store HDF5 data using the .net version of HDF5. The problem is, that data is in an array, after which I write it out to the HDF5 file.

Is there a way to continuously add data to HDF5 in realtime from C#? From what I see on the internet, this is handled by packet table, but I don't see that it is part of the dotnet port?

Comment: Did you find the answer to your question? I also want to use HDF5 with c# and I'm planning to access the file from multiple threads. Is this possible with c#?

Comment: Version 1.10.x of hdf5 will introduce SWMR (single write multiple read) see: https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/release/obtain5110.html
The Hdf.Pinvoke library still uses the 1.8.x version so I don't think it's possible yet.

Answer (score 1):

In hdf5 you can append datasets to an already existing dataset. It is a lot of work to implement it with the low-level methods of the [Hdf.Pinvoke](https://github.com/HDFGroup/HDF.PInvoke) library. I have created a library that adds a layer around these methods to make it easier to read and write hdf5 files. [HDF5DotNetTools](https://github.com/reyntjesr/Hdf5DotnetTools). It's still an early version but you can append data to a file.
There's an example of appending data to existing data in the readme and also in the unit tests of the project.

Here's part of the code:

```
int fileId = Hdf5.CreateFile(filename);    
// Create a dataset and append two more datasets to it. 
// The dsets list are three 10 by 5 matrices
using (var chunkedDset = new ChunkedDataset<double>("/test", fileId, dsets.First()))
{
  foreach (var ds in dsets.Skip(1))
    chunkedDset.AppendDataset(ds);
}
Hdf5.CloseFile(fileId);
```

Answer (score 0):

To continuously add data to HDF5 in real-time (and without knowing how many rows of data exist *a priori*) you need to work with an extendible dataset.

Assuming that you are not bound to a particular API, take a look at [HDFql](http://www.hdfql.com) as it may greatly alleviate you from the low-level details of HDF5. Using HDFql in C# your use-case could be solved as follows (this is just an example - we assume that you have a function named `acquire` that populates variable `values` with a timestamp (UNIX Epoch Time) and an acquired value):

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using AS.HDFql;

// declare structures
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 0)]
struct Data
{
    public int timestamp;
    public float reading;
}

public class Example
{
    public static void Main(string []args)
    {
        // declare variables
        Data values;
        int number;

        // create an HDF5 file named 'data.h5' and use (i.e. open) it
        HDFql.Execute("CREATE AND USE FILE data.h5");

        // create a dataset named 'dset' of data type compound composed of two members named 'timestamp' (of data type int containing a UNIX Epoch Time)
        // and 'reading' (of data type float containing an acquired value). The dataset starts with 0 rows and can grow (i.e. be extended) in an unlimited fashion
        HDFql.Execute("CREATE DATASET dset AS COMPOUND(timestamp AS INT, reading AS FLOAT)(0 TO UNLIMITED)");

        // register variable 'values' for subsequent use (by HDFql)
        number = HDFql.VariableRegister(values);

        // call hypothetical function 'acquire' that populates variable 'values' with a timestamp and an acquired value
        while(acquire(values))
        {
            // alter (i.e. change) dimension of dataset 'dset' to +1 (i.e. add a new row at the end of 'dset')
            HDFql.Execute("ALTER DIMENSION dset TO +1");

            // insert (i.e. write) data from variable 'values' into the last row of dataset 'dset' (thanks to a point selection)
            HDFql.Execute("INSERT INTO dset[-1] VALUES FROM MEMORY " + number);
        }
    }
}
```

Please check HDFql [reference manual](http://www.hdfql.com/resources/HDFqlReferenceManual.pdf) to get additional information on how to work with extendible datasets using this library.